# How do I download msys2?

Tags: installation, ssl-certificate, mingw-w64, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I have been trying to download MSYS2 but have run into quite a few errors. I would like to try out some C++ development so wanted to download it onto my windows 11 laptop. By following the instructions found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_example-install-mingwx64-on-windows), I selected the vscode option on the Start Menu shortcuts (using the installation wizard). When I got to step 6, it came up with these errors (cut down for Overflow's character limit):

```
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-13.1.0-6-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-ada-13.1.0-6-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-python-3.10.11-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
warning: too many errors from mirror.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-objc-13.1.0-6-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-fortran-13.1.0-6-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-ada-13.1.0-6-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-python-3.10.11-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-13.1.0-6-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
warning: too many errors from repo.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
```

And so on...

When addressing this issue, I found this [stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69348953/certificate-error-when-trying-to-install-msys2-packages-on-windows-server) and this [FAQ question](https://www.msys2.org/docs/faq/#how-can-i-make-msys2pacman-trust-my-companys-custom-tls-ca-certificate) (Q2). However, it came up with this new error when I did the curl command:

```bash
$ curl --fail --silent --show-error -I https://repo.msys2.org -o /dev/null && echo "OK!"
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcert.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

How can I fix this?

(Edit): The computer is on my school system so it is likely to go through an SSL interception proxy. Errors include: 
(1) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain 
(2) SSL connection timeout 
(3) Could not resolve host: repo.casualgamer.ca 
(4) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to [website]:443 
(5) OpenSSL/3.1.0: error:0A0003E8:SSL routines::reason(1000) 
(6) Could not resolve host: [website]

Comment: Text-based commands and their output should be posted as properly-formatted text instead of screenshots.  That being said, I carefully typed that `curl` command into my installation of MSYS2 and got `OK` as the result.  The SSL problem has presumably been fixed already by the MSYS2 administrators.

Comment: Or, you are going through an SSL interception/inspection proxy.

Comment: What if you open https://repo.msys2.org in browser and look at the cert manually? Whose cert is it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Issued by CN is proxy.ukcloud.netsweeper.com

Comment: That would be the SSL interception proxy then. You're probably at your place of work and they use that to inspect internet traffic. You'll have to download the proxy's certificate and tell curl that you trust it. I'm not a curl expert so I don't know the option to do it.

Comment: curl was just for testing. Once I get the proxy certificate, how should I use it for msys2?

Comment: My school has trusted and unblocked the sites mentioned in the installation errors, yet I still get the same ones. Could the problem be possibly something else? Or was that the wrong way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some HTTPS man-in-the middle like a proxy or firewall doing SSL interception.

You can probably ignore this with the curl flag `-k` or `--insecure`.

If you just need the build tools and not the MSYS2 shell you can get stanalone MinGW-w64 build tools from https://winlibs.com/